# Oracle SQL - Finding records from table1 where table2 condition does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables. Table1 would be the main table.
Table2 contains data related to table1.

Table1:

```
WONUM
123
124
125
```

Table2:

```
wonum    task     holdstatus
123        1        APPR
123        2        APPR
123        3        APPR

124        1        COMP
124        2        APPR

125        1        COMP
125        2        COMP
```

I want to select ALL wonum from table1 where table1.wonum = table2.wonum and there are NO records with a table2.HOLDSTATUS = 'COMP'

Any help would be great.

The closet I got was:

```
select * from table1 where
exists (select 1 from table2 where table1.wonum=table2.wonum and holdstatus != 'COMP');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've almost got the right answer.
Try this query:

```
SELECT t1.wonum
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.wonum NOT IN (
  SELECT t2.wonum
  FROM table2 t2
  WHERE t2.wonum = t1.wonum
  AND t2.holdstatus = 'COMP'
);
```

This should give you all of the records you need. In this case, just record 123.

You can also do it using a NOT EXISTS query. Generally, they perform better, but if you have a small table, then it wouldn't make that much of a difference.

```
SELECT t1.wonum
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT t2.wonum
  FROM table2 t2
  WHERE t2.wonum = t1.wonum
  AND t2.holdstatus = 'COMP'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close, you just need to use a `NOT EXISTS` and reverse your `holdstatus` condition:

```
Select  *
From    table1  t1
Where Not Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    table2  t2
    Where   t1.wonum = t2.wonum
    And     t2.holdstatus = 'COMP'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be you need a where in

```
select * from table1 
where wonum in (select distinct wonum  from table2  holdstatus != 'COMP');
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different solution could be with outer join:

```
select t1.wonum
from table1  t1
     left outer join table2 t2
     on t1.wonum = t2.wonum
        and t2.holdstatus = 'COMP'
where t2.wonum is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent to the other examples but not using "not exists"

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
WHERE  'COMP' <> ALL (SELECT t2.holdstatus
                     FROM   tables t2
                     WHERE  t2.wonum = t1.wonum);
```